# Why does hydrogen bonding cause a broad stretch in IR spectroscopy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

So hydrogen bonding is an intermolecular forces. I'm assuming that the hydrogen bonding strength varies between molecules and some molecules won't undergo hydrogen bonding causing different bond lengths and stretch frequencies.

Comment: Or that the intermolecular distances vary, unlike in a molecular bond where they're relatively stable (although, consider molecules like ammonia, which flips back and forth, as in a MASER).